# Removing Scuff Mark from a Rear Tail Light

Tags: tail-lights

So there's a minor scuff mark on the rear tail light of my VW Golf, the result of a collision between it and a plastic suitcase while I was loading the suitcase in the car. It's not a major thing, but still - I'd like to get it off.

What's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Mirror or light?

Comment: @Rig Woops. Tail light, corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The most common way to handle this will be rubbing compound and preferably a power drill or buffer. If this is a tail light it is likely a plastic of some kind. You can polish out minor surface scratches with rubbing compound and a buffing wheel.

This of course depends on if this is a scuff or what most would call a scratch. If the depth is significant there isn't much you will be able to do. If it isn't places like Jiffy Lube offer a relatively quick and cheap polish surface for dehazing headlights that may be sufficient. Or, your local auto parts store likely sells a kit designed for the same purpose that could work.